# share a local mercural project

Tags: mercurial, ssh

I started some local mercurial projects which I would like to start sharing.
I use ubuntu and netbeans, and I have a ssh machine which would host the projectes.

How could I "upload" them to the server so other users could download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [A tour of Mercurial: the basics](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html) section "Sharing changes over a network". One of the hosting options is [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/).

Comment: I used to share my changes over a samba share (on windows); is there a way to do the same over ssh without server?

Comment: I did it. I took my local copy, and "cloned" it to the ssh location.